# Select a specific record from xml record using Postgresql

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I have a column in my table called data_xml that has records presented like this-

```
<data user_id="A" user_id_type="1" date="2019-10-31"/>
<data user_id="B" user_id_type="2" date="2020-01-30"/>
```

I want to be able to pull user_id_type records from the column. I tried using `split_part` but because the xml data doesnot have a delimiter as seen above I am not sure how to proceed.

Does anyone have a better alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`xpath()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING-XPATH) for that:

```
select (xpath('/data/@user_id_type', data_xml::xml))[1]
from the_table;
```

`xpath()` returns a array of all matches, that's why the `[1]` is needed.

Comment: i get the following error when I try the above in DBviz -  function xpath(unknown, character varying) does not exist. Jint: no function matches the given name and argument type. you may need to add explicit type casts. Not sure why?

Comment: Also I need to pull all the user_id_type. Should I have [2] instead of [1] ?

Comment: Then apparently you don't have a `xml` but a `varchar` column - you need to cast it to `xml`. Use `@user_id_type` if you want that attribte

Comment: thanks a_horse_with_no_name How do I cast varchar to xml using the xpath() function

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name